# BxSlider starts on wrong slide in FireFox

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have strange issues with BxSlider in FireFox 65.0.1 (64-bit).

The first issue slider starts on the wrong slide compare to Chrome or Edge. 
Second issue very strange behaviour instead of move slides 1 by 1(moveSlides: 1),  when the page loaded slider moves 3 slides and after moves slide 1 by 1 as it should be. Have no issues in Chrome or Edge everything works perfectly. This is my code:

```
        jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
        var spen = $('.slider-one').show().bxSlider();
            var widthMatch = matchMedia("all and (max-width: 767px)");
            var widthHandler = function(matchList) {
                if (matchList.matches) {
                spen.reloadSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true,
                speed: 1000,
                slideSelector: '.items',
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 1,
                moveSlides: 1,
                slideWidth: 450,
                slideMargin:10,
                responsive:true,
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                pause: 10000,
                preloadImages: 'all'
                    })
                } else {
                spen.reloadSlider({
                auto: true,
                autoControls: true,
                autoHover: true,
                speed: 3000,
                slideSelector: '.items',
                minSlides: 3,
                maxSlides: 3,
                moveSlides: 1,
                slideWidth: 600,
                slideMargin:3,
                responsive:false,
                adaptiveHeight: false,
                pause: 5000,
                preloadImages: 'all'
                    })
                }
            };
            widthMatch.addListener(widthHandler);
            widthHandler(widthMatch);
           });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to analyze your issue without working code. Could you create a jsfiddle example?

From what you provided, I saw that the `moveSlides: 1` parameter for the `else` block is incorrect. The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bxslider) states:

> **moveSlides**
>
> The number of slides to move on transition. This value must be >= minSlides, and <= maxSlides. If zero (default), the number of fully-visible slides will be used.

That could explain why it moves 3 slides on page load

Comment: Issue was with Total Cache plugin. Cleared all caches and issue gone.